# How to write a one delete command to replace the three sql with?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

```
create table tmp(select  * from process  
                 where time in (select max(time) from process  
                                group by class,date));
drop table process;
rename table tmp to process;
```

Now i want to write a one delete command to replace the above three sql with.

My tries:

```
delete  from process  
where time not in (select max(time) from process  
                   group by class,date);
```

> ERROR 1093 (HY000): Table 'process' is specified twice, both as a
>   target for 'DELETE' and as a separate source for data

```
delete  from a  
where a.time not in (select max(time) from process a 
                     group by class,date);
```

> ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'learningProcess.a' doesn't exist

Comment: In your last statement, `a` doesn't work since it's out of scope.

Comment: You want to keep only the latest row for each class and date? Step 1 would be to store date and time as a single entity. But all that said, I'm not convinced that a single query would be any faster than 3

Comment: Remove one of the `from process` statements in the first attempted query.